# on groups that generated subgroups by two elements are cyclic

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group where $\langle x , y\rangle$ is cyclic for any $x,y\in G$.
Is $G$ necessarily cyclic?

My attempt: I think if $G$ is finitely generated, then it is true.
But I don't know if this is true for the general case.

Comment: You are right with the case of finitely generated $G$. For if $n$ is the minimal number of generators and we assume $n>1$, $G=\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n\rangle$, then $\langle x_{n-1},x_n\rangle=\langle y\rangle$ for some $y$ and hence $G=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_{n-2},y\rangle$ contradicting minimality.

Comment: What's correct is that in such a group $G$, every finitely generated subgroup is cyclic (by an immediate induction on the number of generators); that's called "locally cyclic". A group is locally cyclic iff it's isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbf{Q}$ or $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, let $G$ be a group of all complex roots of 1 of degrees $p^n$, $n=0,1,\ldots$, where $p$ is a prime. Then $G$ noncyclic, but any finite subset of $G$ generates cyclic subgroup.

Comment: Also $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.